# What does $E[ \cdot ]$ attach to in an expression?

Tags: expected-value

I'm trying to understand/recall, what does $E[ \cdot ]$ attach to?

E.g. if the expression is

$$\beta = (X^T V^{-1}X)^{-1} X^T V^{-1}y$$

then why is

$$E[\beta] = (X^T V^{-1}X)^{-1} X^T V^{-1} E[y]$$

?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$E[\cdot]$ ``attaches'' itself to whatever is inside. So in the example, if 
$$ \beta = (X^TV^{-1}X)^{-1} X^TV^{-1} y,$$

then using the expectation operator,
$$ E[\beta] = E[(X^TV^{-1}X)^{-1} X^TV^{-1} y].$$

However, to go to the next step, we need to understand what is the expectation with reference to? Is it with reference to the joint distribution of $X$ and $y$ or the conditional distribution of $y \mid X$. If it is with reference to the joint distribution of $X$ and $y$, then the next step is not possible. If however it is with respect to the conditional distribution of $y \mid X$ (which is true in most regression problems), we can use the property of expectation that if $y$ is a random variable and $a$ is a constant, then $E[ay] = aE[y]$.

Since $(X^TV^{-1}X)^{-1} X^TV^{-1}$ is a constant when $X$ is given (assuming $V$ is not random)
$$ E[\beta] = (X^TV^{-1}X)^{-1} X^TV^{-1}E[ y].$$

Comment: Excellent answer about a confusing notational point.  When I was learning stats, the lack of qualification on the expectation sign was a point of great confusion for me.